# Handedness of Matrix4x4 camera methods

Tags: c#, .net-4.6

.NET framework 4.6 instroduced new classes in `System.Numerics` namespace including `Matrix4x4`. It also introduced new static helper methods for 3D computer graphics like `CreateLookAt` or `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView`.

Since DirectX and OpenGL differ in "handedness" (DirectX uses lef-handed coordinates while OpenGL right-handed coordinates), usually such APIs are available in both versions and annotated with either `RH` or `LH` to prevent confusion. That is not the case with `System.Numerics`, where we have only one version of each method.

My question is, what is the handedness of new `System.Numerics` methods?

Comment: The native coordinate system in OpenGL is actually left-handed. Most people choose to specify their geometry in a right-handed system, and use a perspective matrix that flips the handedness.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Agreed. In the age of shaders and decline of fixed function pipeline you can do both LH in RH in DirectX and OpenGL. It's just that most tutorials/articles on the web use LH in DirectX and RH in OpenGL, so it's easier to go with it if you are learning 3D graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely enough, all methods are using right-handed coordinates, contrary to Microsoft's own DirectX.